# Swift. Sort array of structs using property name from string variable

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have simple code:

```
struct User {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

var users: [User] = [User(id:1, name:"Alpha"), User(id:2, name:"Beta"), User(id:3, name:"Gamma")]

print(users)
users.sort { $0.name > $1.name }
print(users)
```

What is the best way of changing the sorting field based on variable? I mean, I want to have some variable like "sortBy" which contains value of sorting field ("id", "name" etc, struct may contain dozens of fields).
And I can't find out the proper way of doing so in Swift.

Pseudo-code:

```
var sortBy = "name"
users.sort { $0.{sortBy} > $1.{sortBy} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use key paths and methods.

```swift
users.sort(by: \.name)
users.sort(by: \.id)
```

```swift
extension Array where Element == User {
  mutating func sort<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    by comparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable
  ) rethrows {
    self = try sorted(by: comparable, >)
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// Sorted by a common `Comparable` value, and sorting closure.
  func sorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    by comparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable,
    _ areInIncreasingOrder: (Comparable, Comparable) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> [Element] {
    try sorted {
      try areInIncreasingOrder(comparable($0), comparable($1))
    }
  }
}
```